# Calculate the expected value of E{e^(ax+by)} , where x~N(μ1,σ1^2) and y~N(μ2,σ2^2)

Tags: statistics

I got a problem of calculating E{e^(ax+by)}, where $X\sim N(μ_1,σ_1^2)$, $Y\sim N(μ_2,σ_2^2)$.    $a$ and $b$ are constants.
   I got the result by myself,is it right? the reulsts is shown in figure.

If it is wrong, can you give me the right answer?  Thank you ver much!
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSrj0.jpg)

[image]

Comment: So you do not know if X and Y are independent or not ?

Comment: It cannot be calculated. What lacks is the *joint*-distribution of $X$ and $Y$. Also first wonder what the distribution of $aX+bY$ looks like and base your calculations on that knowledge.

Comment: Yes， I don't know . if  X and Y are independent , the answers are ?  I am majoring in communication,so i know a little about this . This puzzlement had been haunting my mind for a long time. I hope that you can give  me some clues.

Comment: @Paul That´s true-good point. That´s why I didn´t mention the independence in my answer.

Comment: @ callculus @Paul     Thanks for your answers! Finally I need to calculate the expected value of $E(e^{a(X_1+X_2)+i(Y_1+Y_2})$;                      
where $X_1\sim N(0,σ_1^2),,X_2\sim N(0,σ_1^2),,Y_1\sim N(0,σ_2^2),,Y_2\sim N(0,σ_2^2);;$a is constant;   $i$ is imaginary unit

Comment: @Paul It **does matter**. See my answer.

Comment: @Paul Sorry but for some given distributions of U and V, E(UV) very much depends on whether U and V are independent or not.

Comment: @张兴民 Maybe you do not realize this but this page is slowly turning into a mess, due to your silence on two key points: 1. Are X and Y assumed to be jointly normal? 2. Are X and Y assumed to be independent? (Note that if the answer to 2 is "yes", then the answer to 1 is "yes" as well.)

Comment: @drhab, you're right, the exponentiation changes things.

Answer (score 2):

In this answer it is preassumed that $X,Y$ have a joint normal distribution.

---

Let it be that $Z$ has normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Denoting its moment generating function by $M_Z(t):=\mathbb Ee^{tZ}$  and making use of [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples) $M_Z(t)=e^{t\mu+\frac12\sigma^2t^2}$ we find by substitution $t=1$: $$\mathbb Ee^Z=M_Z(1)=e^{\mu+\frac12\sigma^2}\tag1$$

We can apply this on $Z:=aX+bY$ (wich has normal distribution here) by observing that:

- $\mu=\mathbb E[aX+bY]=a\mathbb EX+b\mathbb EY=a\mu_1+b\mu_2$
- $\sigma^2=\text{Var}(aX+bY)=a^2\sigma_1^2+2ab\text{Covar}(X,Y)+b^2\sigma_2^2$

Now substitute these parameters in $(1)$ and you are ready.

Also note that we need to know the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ for this, which is not one of the data in your question. That explains my comment: "It cannot be calculated."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(e^{aX+bY})&=&E(e^{aX})E(e^{bY})=M_X(a)M_Y(b)=e^{\mu_1 a+\frac{\sigma^2_1 a^2}{2}}e^{\mu_2 b+\frac{\sigma^2_2 b^2}{2}}\\
            &=&\exp\left[\mu_1a+\mu_2b+\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_1^2a^2+\sigma_2^2b^2)\right]
\end{eqnarray*}

where $M_X$ is the moment generating function of $X$, $M_Y$ is the mgf of $Y$

Comment: how to prove $X$ and $Y$ are independent ?

Comment: if $x$ and $y$ are not  independent,how to caculate the question?

Comment: If $b$ is imaginary unit $i$,  are they  the same ?

Comment: @张兴民 Note that in the answer the variable $t$ is missing.

Comment: @ callculus   Thank  you very much!

Comment: we cannot prove the independency between of $X$ and $Y$ with the information we have in the problem

Comment: if they are not independent, then how to deal with it depends on the situation and another information we have, if they $X$ and $Y$ have bivariate normal distribution, then we can use similar (but not same) method as before, but if they don't, we have to use another way, and once again, it depends on the situation

Comment: $t$? where is $t$?

Comment: if $b=i$, we can use characteristic function of normal distribution, but actually the formula is really similar

Comment: @ Rizky Reza Fujisaki   Thank you! I understand you.  I have the same question. $t$?  where is $t$?

Comment: @张兴民 This deals with the special case $t=1$. That's why there is no $t$ visible in the answer. The substitution $t=1$ has taken place allready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the moment generating function of the normal distribution [(see here )](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Examples) .

$E\left(e^{atX+btY}\right)= M_X(ta)\cdot  M_Y(tb)$

with $M_X(ta)=\large{e^{a\mu_X t+a^2\frac12 \sigma_X ^2 t^2}}$

and $M_Y(tb)=\large{e^{b\mu_Y t+b^2\frac12 \sigma_Y ^2 t^2}}$

Note that always $t$ is involved.

---

The mgf for $Z\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ can be derived as follows

$E\left(e^{tZ}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tz}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-1/2\ z}\, dz$

$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\large{e^{-1/2(z^2-2tz+t^2)+1/2t^2}}\, dz$

$=e^{1/2t^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\large{\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-1/2(z-t)^2}}_{\text{pdf of Z}}}\, dz$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\large{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-1/2(z-t)^2}}\, dz=1$

Thus $M_Z(t)=e^{1/2t^2}$

Comment: @ callculus Yes. I still want to know the mathematical meaning of $t$.  what't the relationship $t$ and 'independence' or 'nonindependence'? Or they have no relationship.

Comment: Assuming that X and Y are independent.